Receive logs, traces and metrics from the same receiver and forward them to different backends
I have deployed an open-telemetry collector in Kubernetes with the helm chart.
It takes data from several services running a java agent that ships logs, metrics and traces in otlp format.
I want to forward logs to Loki, traces to Tempo, and metrics to Prometheus.
How can I separate this information in a pipeline? Do I have to filter by data type in the collector pipeline?

There is no need of filtering, because each signal can have own pipeline, e.g.:
  pipelines:
    traces:
      receivers: [otlp]
      processors: [batch]
      exporters: [tempo]
    metrics:
      receivers: [otlp]
      processors: [batch]
      exporters: [prometheus]
    logs:
      receivers: [otlp]
      processors: [batch]
      exporters: [loki]

Of course I didn't use real exporters types/names in the snippet - those are just examples to illustrate how that "filtering" works.
